# Koin Unit testing how to verify whether a class method was called when injected by "by inject()"

Tags: android, unit-testing, koin

I have a class for which I have written unit tests. The class injects 2 other classes via the constructor. However due to cyclic dependency issues, I had to inject one of the other dependencies via by inject().

My class looks as the follows:

```
class AuthUseCase(
    private val accessTokenUseCase: AccessTokenUseCase,
    private val refreshTokenRepo: RefreshTokenRepo
) : KoinComponent {

    val notificationService: NotificationService by inject()



    fun getSyncedAccessToken(loginResult: LoginResult): Token? {
        return when (loginResult) {
            is LoginResult.Success -> {
                accessTokenUseCase.storeRefreshToken(loginResult.accessToken)
                notificationService.init()
                loginResult.accessToken.accessToken
            }
            is LoginResult.Failure -> {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test if notificationService.init was fired or not in my test.
Normally it would be as simple as

```
verify(notificationService).init()
```

However I cannot understand how to mock this class. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this one will help? https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/197#issuecomment-429768448

Comment: @MariuszBrona really coincidental but I was just checking the implementation for it. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mariuz and through this post:
https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/197#issuecomment-429768448

The trick is to start an empty Koin container. And load mocked module in the test.

```
@Test
fun testGetValidAccessTokenIfInvalidAccessTokenIsPassed() {
    notificationService = mock()
    startKoin { }
    loadKoinModules(module {
        single {
            notificationService
        }
    })
   

    verify(notificationService).init()
}
```

Comment: Happy to help with that one! Cool!